how to add this animation in flutter, container filled sliding animation
i am creating a new app, which consister 3 payment tiers,represented by three filled containers.
i want to add this type of animation to this
i tried size Transition but that is not working according to my needs, the tiles should be exapanded when i click on them and close other containers.
how can i do that.

help is appriciated.

There a lot of packages that provide such thing, but personally i would suggest the native expansion panel widget.
Look at the following:
Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(),
        body: Column(
          children: [
            ExpansionPanelList(
              expansionCallback: (index, isExpanded) {
                setState(() { //this for loop just closes previous open Panels
                  for (int i = 0; i < booleanList.length; i++) {
                    booleanList[i] = false;
                  }
                  booleanList[index] = !booleanList[index];
                });
              },
              children: [
                ExpansionPanel(
                  isExpanded: booleanList[0],
                  backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                  headerBuilder: (context, expanded) {
                    return Text('Payment 1');
                  },
                  body: Column( // put whatever widgets you want in the body
                    children: [
                      Text('Content 1 '),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                ExpansionPanel(
                  isExpanded: booleanList[1],
                  backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
                  headerBuilder: (context, expanded) {
                    return Text('Payment 2');
                  },
                  body: Column(
                    children: [
                      Text('Content 2 '),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                ExpansionPanel(
                  isExpanded: booleanList[2],
                  backgroundColor: Colors.green,
                  headerBuilder: (context, expanded) {
                    return Text('Payment 3');
                  },
                  body: Column(
                    children: [
                      Text('Content 3 '),
                    ],
                  ),
                )
              ],
            )
          ],
        )
);

which gives that:

